# How to center abs pos box inside already centered wrapper?

Tags: css

How does one center an absolutely positioned box inside an already centered wrapper?

Ie. this:

[image]

Should be:

[image]

```css
.main {
    height: 300px;
    background: lightgrey;
    display: flex;
}
.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    background: blue;
    text-align: center;
}
.dropdown a {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <a>Lorem</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <a>Lorem ipsum</a>
          <a>Dolor sit amet consectetur</a>
          <a>Adipisicing elit</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you're positioning absolute you want to define the width of your div and then do a margin to the same direction you're positioned absolute from. That margin distance should be half of your defined width.

In this case:

```
    left:50%;
    width:200px;
    margin-left:-100px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pqfq3m6z/

```
 .main {
        height: 300px;
        background: lightgrey;
        display: flex;
    }
    .wrapper {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .dropdown {
        position: absolute;
        color: white;
        background: blue;
        text-align: center;
        left:50%;
        width:200px;
        margin-left:-100px;
    }
    .dropdown a {
        display: block;
    }
```

Comment: Hi! So there's no way without explicitly defining the width? Not even using all this new flexbox magic?

Comment: If you don't need it to be position:absolute; you can just use margin: auto...
http://jsfiddle.net/pqfq3m6z/1/

Comment: I would prefer position absolute as this is a dropdown and I use it for all my dropdowns. However if that isn't possible, I can make an exception. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkBoulder - The thing here is absolute positioning.  No matter how magical flexbox is, absolute positioning is still absolute positioning.  It effectively takes the element out of the normal flow of the document and applies it's own set of rules.  In other words, position absolute trumps flexbox or anything else for that matter.  What you need to ask yourself is this...  Based on your use case, should you be using flexbox and some other alignment code, or do you need to be using absolute positioning.  If it's A, you don't need to, nor should you use B.  If it's B, then you don't need A.

Comment: Great answer, thank you so much for your insight. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the position to relative.

e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/7vgxug6k/

```
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    background: blue;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**Edit: To center the hyperlink too:** http://jsfiddle.net/7vgxug6k/2/

Comment: Unfortunately the `<a>Lorem</a>` needs to be centered as well.

Comment: I'd rather not set an explicit width (see comment in cport's answer). Most likely the only option is to remove positioning altogether. Cheers!